# How can I convert SQLite 2 to SQLite3 using Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, sqlite2

I'm trying to convert a SQLite 2 file to SQLite3 using Python on Windows.  On Linux, I'd just pipe a dump from `sqlite` to `sqlite3`:

```
os.system("sqlite db.sqlite .dump | sqlite3 db3.sqlite")
```

On Windows, I have no such convenient means of transferring the dump.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
sqlite_dump = os.popen('sqlite %s .dump' % sqlite_db).read()

open(sqlite_dump_file, "w").write(sqlite_dump)

os.system("del %s" % sqlite_db)
os.system("sqlite3 -init %s %s" % (sqlite_db,
                             sqlite_dump_file))
```

This works, but it leaves me at a `sqlite3` prompt.  I've tried the `-bail` switch and added `"\n.quit\n" to the end of the SQLite dump, but to no avail.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you pipe it similarly on Windows? What goes wrong when you do it?

Comment: Honestly? I had no idea you could do that on Windows, so I didn't even try.